# Unable to Connect to Azure Blob Storage Endpoint from a specific server

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, azure-blob-storage

We've been using Azure blob storage for storing all of our SQL backups for over 8 months now.

Over the weekend our production server has suddenly stopped being able to reach the Azure Blob Storage Endpoint where the backups are stored too. The SQL Jobs are now failing.

The back up worked as normal on the A.M job and then failed on the same given day on the P.M run and it hasn't worked since.

We've tried using the Azure blob storage viewer for this specific endpoint from our local machines and also another of our development servers and they can all connect without any issue.

It appears that the issue lies with the server itself, but I'm unsure as to where the problem lies.

Ideally, we need to be able to fix the issue without rebooting the server as its our production server.

I'm a developer, and Azure SQL backup mgmt is not my strong point, would appreciate some guidance on this issue.

Comment: Is there an error message you're getting?

Comment: ts a standard  I/O error when the job tries to reach the Azure Blob storage, endpoint, its odd because all othe rmachines can reach the same instance without issue.

Comment: Using the specific server that cannot connect, are you able to connect to a different blob storage endpoint?

Comment: We havent got another account. Weve had to wait until out of hours, and reboot the production server. It seems to have fixed it. I have no idea what caused that issue.